# F# library not recogniced in Xamarin Studio but compiles fine

Tags: c#, f#, xamarin, monodevelop

I'm developing a .Net library in Xamarin Studio and I am following the [The F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/)/

I have added a reference to the F# library project from C# test project and both projects are set to 4.5

Using the F# library in the C# NUnit test works fine and the solution compiles fine. Tests run fine as well, but editor does not recognize the namespace/Library. When using VS 2012 the code completion works as expected.

Building with FAKE on both OS X, Ubuntu and Windows works fine as well.

Is there any way I can get Xamarin Studio to recognize my F# lib ?

Comment: what version of mono and Xamarin Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using mono 3.12.1 and Xamarin 5.7.2 (build 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code completion from F# to C# and viceversa, is yet not supported by XamarinStudio as far as I know.

What works is C# to C# and F# to F#. But I think Xamarin employees are working on this (i.e. you could try the `roslyn` branch from [this repo](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop), compiling from sources).

EDIT: This is no longer true, Xamarin Studio 6.0 (now in beta at the time of this writing) provides C# to F# and F# to C# completion and "Find references" features.